# Voice to Math Symbol Conversion

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

May I take liberty to suggest regarding the topic..

After Jeroen's query I tried out basic Google voice inputs; it indicated user voice route was at all feasible. Anna so gracefully shared her math scripting experience with others. At the end she said:

> " Hope something here can help you out, too."

... in fact leading a way for more gifted.

An additional feature provided to SE Math users converting speech to symbolic math text would be most welcome by users as can be seen in their overwhelming responses.

Any subscriptions needed for related outsourced task would be readily met by users it appears.

It also suggests the next step .. an initiative by SE Math Meta for such a provision here, *a means to key in by voice* would be appreciated by one and all, able or challenged, at the keyboard...

[Voice to Math Symbol Conversion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1833459/math-without-pencil-and-paper/1833618#1833618)

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1425/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I doubt that Stack Exchange has the resources to accomplish this at all; voice recognition is a very difficult task. However, even if they could, they would be competing with software whose sole purpose is voice-to-text recognition and which would likely always outpace SE's capabilities.

This is mind, I think the best thing Stack Exchange can do to accommodate users who can't use a keyboard is to ensure that their site is compatible with existing voice-to-text software. Given that its input is purely text-based, I suspect that users who have a setup for writing LaTeX with one's voice will be able to write here.

Comment: Since these four years has there been any change towards enabling some   limited voice input?